# How To Implement Simple CRUD Search in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table that contains data and I want to implement a search feature to it. Example, I would type a query in the search bar and it would look through similar terms in the table columns and then display the rows that contain matches.

This is the error I keep coming across.

[image]

I just followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWnmOBkHzUo) tutorial and used my variables instead. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I did everything according to it.

Here is my TicketController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Ticket;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\TicketUpdateRequest;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {   
        $tickets= Ticket::latest()->paginate(10);
        return view('tickets.index', compact('tickets'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('tickets.create');
    }

    public function delete(Ticket $ticket)
    {
        return view('tickets.delete', ['tickets' => $tickets]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Ticket::create([
        'summary'=>request('summary'),
        'description'=>request('description'),
        'status'=>request('status'),
        'updated_at'=>request('updated_at'),
        'name_client'=>request('name_client'),
        'contactnum'=>request('contactnum'),
        'location'=>request('location'),
        'rtype'=>request('rtype'),
        'personnel'=>request('personnel'),
        'priority'=>request('priority'),
        'notes'=>request('notes'),
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('tickets.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Ticket  $ticket
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Ticket $ticket)
    {
        return view('tickets.show', compact('ticket'));
    }


    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->get('search');
        $tickets = Ticket::latest('tickets')->orWhere('rtype', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(10);
        return view('tickets.index',['tickets' => $tickets]);
    }



    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Ticket  $ticket
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Ticket $ticket)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Ticket  $ticket
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(TicketUpdateRequest $request, Ticket $ticket)
    {

        $ticket->summary = request('summary');
        $ticket->description = request('description');
        $ticket->status = request('status');
        $ticket->name_client= request('name_client');
        $ticket->contactnum= request('contactnum');
        $ticket->location= request('location');
        $ticket->rtype= request('rtype');
        $ticket->personnel= request('personnel');
        $ticket->priority= request('priority');
        $ticket->notes= request('notes');
        $ticket->save();



        return redirect()->route('tickets.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Ticket  $ticket
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Ticket $ticket)
    {
        $ticket->delete();
        return redirect()->route('tickets.index');
    }
}
```

and the search part of my navbar:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"></form>
```

Here is also the table part of my index page:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket</th>
      <th>Last Updated</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Request Type</th>
      <th>Request Details</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th>Priority</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$ticket->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$ticket->updated_at}}</td>
      <td>{{$ticket->summary}}</td>
      <td>{{$ticket->rtype}}</td>
      <td>{{str_limit($ticket->description, 40)}}</td>
      <td>{{str_limit($ticket->notes, 40)}}</td>
      <td>{{$ticket->priority}}</td>
      <td>{{$ticket->status}}</td>
      <td><a href="/tickets/{{$ticket->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
          <a href="/tickets/delete/{{$ticket->id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and lastly my routes:

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/tickets', 'TicketController@index')->name('tickets.index')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/tickets/create','TicketController@create')->name('tickets.create')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/tickets/create','TicketController@store')->name('tickets.store')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/tickets/{ticket}','TicketController@update')->name('tickets.update')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/tickets/delete/{ticket}','TicketController@delete')->name('tickets.delete')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/tickets/delete/{ticket}','TicketController@destroy')->name('tickets.destroy')->middleware('auth');


Route::get('/tickets/{ticket}','TicketController@show')->name('tickets.show')->middleware('auth');



Route::get('/', 'TicketController@index');
Route::get('/search','TicketController@search');
Route::resource('tickets','TicketController');

Route::get('/clientrequest','ClientRequestController@create')->name('clientrequest');

Route::post('/clientrequest','ClientRequestController@store')->name('clientrequest');


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::get('admin/routes', 'HomeController@admin')->middleware('admin');
```

EDIT: This is my model:

[image]

Comment: can you show tickets model?

Comment: where can I find tickets model? sorry I'm new to Laravel

Comment: The model you created,in the tutorial he created posts model i think

Comment: I added the model now. thank you

Comment: try adding  protected $primaryKey='ticketID'; or what ever your primary key is in your database

Answer (score 0):

The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by default to date or by column.

```
Ticket::latest('tickets')->orWhere('rtype', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(10);
```

In your eloquent query you are passing the `tickets` column for the orderBy(latest) query.
While it does not exist in your table. Changing it to order by date `created_at` or any other column should resolve the error.

```
Ticket::Where('rtype', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->latest()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing happens when I search the page just reloads but the URI changes to /search

Comment: @TylerJoseph, You'll also need ajax, and also did you try passing a search query that doesn't exists in your database, to see if it returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

Create Route

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserMasterController@index')->name('user');
Route::get('/add', 'UserMasterController@add')->name('user.add');
Route::post('/add_record', 'UserMasterController@add_record')->name('user.add_record');
Route::get('/edit_user/{id}', 'UserMasterController@edit_user')->name('user.edit_user');
Route::post('/update_user/{id}', 'UserMasterController@update_user')->name('user.update_user');
Route::any('/delete/{id}', 'UserMasterController@delete')->name('user.delete');
```

Create Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\UserMaster;
use App\Role;
use Validator;
use File;
use DB;

class UserMasterController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $roles = Role::all();
        $users = DB::table('user_master')->simplePaginate(1);
        return view('users.index',compact('users','roles'));
    }

    public function add(){

        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('users.create',compact('roles'));
    }

    public function add_record(Request $request){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:30',
            'email' => 'required|unique:user_master|email',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'role_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        $customers = new UserMaster;
        $customers->name = $request->input('name');
        $customers->email = $request->input('email');
        $customers->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $customers->role_id = $request->input('role_id');

        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');
            $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        }

        $customers->image = $filename;
        $customers->save();

        return redirect()->action('UserMasterController@index');
    }

    public function edit_user(Request $request,$id){

        $roles = Role::all();
        $users = UserMaster::find($id);
        $selectedRole = UserMaster::first()->role_id;
        return view('users.edit',compact('users','roles','selectedRole'));
    }

    public function update_user(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:30',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'role_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        $customers = UserMaster::find($id);
        $customers->name = $request->input('name');
        $customers->email = $request->input('email');
        $customers->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $customers->role_id = $request->input('role_id');

        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $userimage = UserMaster::select('image')->where('id',$id)->first(); 
            $image_name = basename($userimage->image);
            $image_path = public_path('uploads/'.$image_name);
            //dd($image_path);

            if(File::exists($image_path)) {
                File::delete($image_path);
            }

            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');
            $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        }

        $customers->image = $filename;
        $customers->save();
        return redirect()->route('user')
             ->with('success','User updated successfully');
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        UserMaster::find($id)->delete($id);
        return redirect()->route('user')
            ->with('success','User delete successfully');

    }
}
```

Create Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Role;

class UserMaster extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_master';

    public function roles(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role','user_id');
    }
}
```

Create index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Users</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('user.add') }}"> Create New User</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))

        <div class="alert alert-success">

            <p>{{ $message }}</p>

        </div>

    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered">

        <tr>

            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th width="280">Action</th>

        </tr>

    @foreach ($users as $user)

    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->phone}}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->roles->name}}</td>
        <td><img height="50px" width="50px" class="user-pic" src="<?php echo asset("uploads/$user->image")?>"></td> </td>
        <td>

            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('user.edit_user',$user->id) }}">Edit</a>
                <form action="{{ route('user.delete', $user->id) }}" method="DELETE">
                   <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

                   <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                 </form>
                 <!-- <button class="deleteRecord" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" >Delete Record</button> -->
        </td>
        {{ $users->links() }}
    </tr>

    @endforeach

    </table>
@endsection
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".deleteRecord").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        //var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "destroy/"+id,
            type: 'Post',
            data: { "id": id,  "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (){
                console.log("it Works");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Create form create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')

<div id="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Add User</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form role="form" action="{{ route('user.add_record') }}" id="add_customer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div>

                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('phone') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Phone</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('role_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Role</label>
                                        <select name="role_id" class="form-control" id="role_id">
                                            <option value="">-- Select Role --</option>
                                            @foreach ($roles as $role)
                                            <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ ucfirst($role->name) }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('role_id') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('image') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Image</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control" placeholder="Image">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('image') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div>    
                            <button type="submit" valur="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>

@endsection
```

Create edit form edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')

<div id="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Add Role</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form role="form" action="{{ route('user.update_user',$users->id) }}" id="update_role" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $users->name ?>" placeholder="Name">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $users->email ?>" placeholder="Email">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div>

                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('phone') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Phone</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $users->phone ?>"placeholder="Phone">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('role_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Role</label>
                                        <select name="role_id" class="form-control" id="role_id">
                                            <option value="">-- Select Role --</option>
                                            @foreach ($roles as $role)
                                            <option value="{{ $role->id }}" {{ $selectedRole== $role->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $role->name }}</option> 
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('role_id') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('image') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="name">Image</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control" placeholder="Image">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('image') }}</span>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div>   
                                    <button type="submit" valur="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>

@endsection
```

Create Layout file layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel 5.5 CRUD Application</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            @yield('content')

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```